# Loading an image without knowing the file type

Tags: javascript, html

I have a files named `image1.jpg` and `image2.JPG`. I don't know if the file type is in uppercase or lowercase.

If I do `<img src="image1.JPG">` or `<img src="image2.jpg">` the image won't load.

I have tried a wildcard like this: `<img src = "image1.*">`, but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is beyond html, you will need to use javascript or a server side language. or preferably just change the image name.

Comment: Are both the html file and the images in the same folder? Did you try, maybe, checking in the Javascript console the true value of the src attribute?

Comment: You need to know the URL of the resource you want to display in order to request it. There is no wild card concept in URLs.

Comment: if you do src="image.jpg" this means the image.jpg exists in the same directory as your html page, if it is at a different path, you need to specify that in src

Comment: I know the path of the image file. In the question it is simplified. The image tags are being created programatically in javascript. I just dont know the suffix.

Comment: can't you rename your image files with correct extensions?

Comment: My images are being posted to the server by users. I saw two possible options: 1. change the extension when the image is saved to the server, 2. work with the extensions I have. It looks like it's time to discount option 2. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with simple solution just see my code how me do this issue:
before that you must know your directory of your image or you know src of your image tag you file name and you can do this with my code:

your HTML is same this for example:

```
<img src="https://youradmin.com/uploads/image.*" id="image" />
```

and this javascript:

```
var imageID = document.getElementById('image');
var imageType = ['png', 'jpg', 'webp' , 'jpeg' , 'PNG', 'JPG', 'WEBP', 'JPEG'];
for(var i = 0 ; i < imageType.length; i++ ){
var set = imageID.setAttribute('src' , `https://youradmin.com/uploads/image.${imageType[i]}`);
var load = imageID.complete && imageID.naturalHeight !== 0;
 if(load){
   {break}
  }
}
```

you can do more complexity with use anther array for image name as image1 or image2 and etc.
But I think this can help you and I hope this be helpful for you. GL